# Adding values to an array using a for loop in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, scanf, user-input

So I'm trying to make an array with multiple values.
However, I want the user to be able to not only decide each value, but how many values are in the array itself.
The program doesn't seem to work, though.

Issue at hand is that every time I run my code it runs just fine until it gets to the for loop. The code allows me to input one value but then just exits with the following message:
`Process returned 5 (0x5)   execution time : 2.656 s`

I've tried a couple of other methods but none of them seem to work.
Here's my latest attempt

```
    // Initiate variable
    int iterations;

    printf("Input amount of values: ");
    scanf("%d",&iterations);
    fflush(stdin);

    int listOfValues[iterations];
    fflush(stdin);

    int i;
    int tempvar;

    printf("Input values in order: ");
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++);
    {
        scanf("%d",&tempvar);
        fflush(stdin);
        listOfValues[i] = tempvar;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Please keep in mind I'm still in the stage of learning C and programming in general, so be gentle!

Comment: Please remove the trailing semicolon from `for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++);` That loop has no body, and the subsequent code block is executed once, with `i` out of range.

Comment: Please note that `fflush(stdin)` is not standard C, IIRC only one compiler support it as a non-portable extension. And it's not even needed for your case.

Comment: Aside: Don't bounce through ```tempvar``` and ```ListOfValues```. Input directly into the array and check the return value of ```scanf```.

Answer (score 0):

it a small mistake just remove the semicolon after the for loop.

like this:

```
// Initiate variable
int iterations;

printf("Input amount of values: ");
scanf("%d",&iterations);
fflush(stdin);

int listOfValues[iterations];
fflush(stdin);

int i;
int tempvar;

printf("Input values in order: ");
for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&tempvar);
    fflush(stdin);
    listOfValues[i] = tempvar;
}
```

if we put a semicolon after the for statement it will run just once
hope this helped

Comment: The for loop wouldn't execute the statements after the opening ```{``` .```;``` is a terminating charater and is equivalent to saying ```"do nothing"```. The for loop does not run once, it runs until the conditional expression becomes false, but does nothing. Then a new block opens and the statements inside it are executed.

Comment: And flushing the input buffer invokes Undefined Behaviour in C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the MSVC compiler supported `fflush` on an input stream in the past, but they too now consider it to be *undefined behaviour*. When input to `stdin` is redirected from a file, it is disastrous.